# Jupyter notebooks empty

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

Im not sure what happened but suddenly every single Jupyter notebook on my computer is completely empty when i open them in VS Code. I have not done anything (that i know of) that is different.

Can anyone shine any light here?

Comment: You should specify what you mean as 'empty'? Does that mean there is no content?Or does it mean the output that should be there isn't there and they are opening as unexecuted notebooks? Have you opened them directly in a text editor as text to see the underlying json and verified the json is intact before you try opening them normally as notebooks? If you need something separate from VSCode to do this in, you can go [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements) and launch a temporary Jupyter session by pressing 'launch binder'. Then drag in your notebook file & open with editor.

Comment: I second Wayne's comment. describe in words what you are seeing _and_ also add a screenshot.

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. Also show us what version of the Jupyter extension you have installed. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: related _past, fixed_ issues from googling "`github vscode jupyter issues empty`": https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1042, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/847, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/163470, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1702